# Rhomobile - Application has stopped unexpectedly on device

Tags: rhomobile

My application works well on Rhosimulator but returns error on android device.
It stops with the error "Application (com.process.rhomobile.app_name has stopped unexpectedly"

Please suggest

Comment: Why is this tagged with "PDF"?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche - I removed the PDF tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall the older APK from the phone if you have any & Try Again . Also please run Rake clean:android before Rake Run:android:device

Comment: On simulator it works fine.. And on actual device it returns error, so there is no point of uninstalling anything from the device.   Moreover i cant do this on every device to be used. I dont use Rake command to run.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the same problem is with me also and now I posted a new question on [.apk file build with Rhohub not working on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13270129/1542202) with all the details.

But I found out a work around when building from command prompt go to the applicationfolder/bin/target/android and before the buid finishes copy the appname_debug.apk file and run it in the device it will definitely run but problem again starts it will be around 4 times larger in size and css may or may not work.

Comment: I build the app from Rhostudio and not using command prompt. I do remove the old apk from the device everytime.

Comment: Okk finally my application is built and working as I wanted(< 3mb).So what I did is like this:1.)In Run Configurations I kept the Platform as Android and version of it as 2.2 and Simulator as myavd2.2(whatever name you can use).2.)I made an avd in SDK Manager as myavd2.2(API Level 8).3.)I did not try to run the application with Iphone profile or any other profile.4.)The most important of all which I think why it work out is that I did not change any thing in layout.erb. Try it and give response

Comment: All these changes u r doing on Rhostudio to make it run. But it runs well on my Rhosimulator, problem is with deploying and running it on android device.

Comment: Yeah mine also runs on Rhosimulator but the problem is Emulator and actual device are different,I also don't know what exactly went wrong previously but as I made the app again and did as told above it works fine now with only 2.6 mb. Also one more thing I was constantly checking by building the app after creating 2-3 models to check if its working fine or not.First check by building an .apk for a simple app with 1 model  on the device.Best of luck.

Comment: Even i am trying the same way.. bt i looks more like a common issue people are facing. i am not clear with the sdk thing u talked about above. i think thats required when u want to run with Android simulator. Also, i am not aware of the use of AVD